# How to change specific values on a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
    df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5,3,4,2),B=c(1,2,3,3,4,1,4,2),C=c(2,1,4,5,2,1,3,2), D=c(4,1,2,4,3,4,2,5))
    row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8")

       A B C D
    R1 3 1 2 4
    R2 2 2 1 1
    R3 1 3 4 2
    R4 4 3 5 4
    R5 5 4 2 3
    R6 3 1 1 4
    R7 4 4 3 2
    R8 2 2 2 5
```

I am trying to change values on the column C so that all the values 2 are 1 and all the values 1 are 2 (without rewriting the data frame of course). However, if I just replace them separately with

```
df$C[df$C == 1]<-2
df$C[df$C == 2]<-1
```

it will just change all the values originally 1 and 2 into 1 because I did them in that order. Is there anyway I could do the changes at the same time and to combine the arguments? The outcome should be like this:

```
       A B C D
    R1 3 1 1 4
    R2 2 2 2 1
    R3 1 3 4 2
    R4 4 3 5 4
    R5 5 4 1 3
    R6 3 1 2 4
    R7 4 4 3 2
    R8 2 2 1 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to change the values and overwrite the original column.

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$C == 2, 1, ifelse(df$C == 1, 2, df$C))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I might use mutate with case_when() or mutate with recode()

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5,3,4,2),B=c(1,2,3,3,4,1,4,2),C=c(2,1,4,5,2,1,3,2), D=c(4,1,2,4,3,4,2,5))

row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8")

 df2 <- df %>% 
   mutate(C = case_when(
     C == 1 ~ 2, 
     C == 2 ~ 1, 
     TRUE ~ C
   ))
```